# How to set iframe height on the bases of the given URL height

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Actually, I am not able to set the dynamic height as per the given URL. At that time i am using below code.

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://example.com" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="overflow:auto; width:100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Please suggest me any solution if any possible.

Comment: you cant set the height based on the dynamic urls.

Comment: You can set it on iframe content load. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557933/how-to-set-iframe-height-on-the-bases-of-the-given-url-height/23558028#23558028)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by getting iframe size and make an adjustment accoridng to that like;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe() {
      var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe');
      if( iframe ) {
            iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
            iframe.width = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + "px";
      }   
  }
</script>
```

And in your frame;

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://example.com" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" onload="resizeIframe()"></iframe>
```

**Update:** Cross Domain

If loaded iframe url is different than your domain, you will get permission error due to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). You need to give permission on iframe domain for your domain. Let say;

Iframe Domain: `http://example.com`

Your Domain: `http://yourdomain.com`

In Iframe Domain, Apache conf, you need to set header inside `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>` or `<VirtualHost`>;

```
Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "example.com"
```

If domain is not yours, you can use [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer). Simply, add this library and run;

```
iFrameResize();
```

Comment: I am getting "Permission denied Error" for iframe.contentWindow

Comment: @ManishGupta You are loading an iframe from different domain? If it is different domain, you should give permission on loaded iframe domain for your domain. if `http://example.com` is yours, you can give permission on that domain

Comment: Yes and I know that is the reason.
But Is there any way to call crossdomain url and then set its height weight.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But where I will have to give permission on iframe domain for your domain?? 
Not able to get the last line.

Comment: But Iframe domain is not yours right? You can not use that option

Comment: Oh I see. Okey, Let us assume that its my domain. Then where I will have to write this permission? Or please provide me any link where I can get it.

Comment: @ManishGupta you can see my updated answer. You can set it in apache web server conf

Comment: @ManishGupta if domain is not yours, you can do that with a library called iframe-resizer. See my updated answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52360/discussion-between-manish-gupta-and-huseyin-babal)